# Finding strings that have common words in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql, I have 2 tables

```
emp(id int, name varchar, dept_id int)
dept(id int, name varchar)
```

I would like to get the employees with the following restriction:
The employee name has at least 1 common word with his/her department name.

The solution can be a select statement or a stored procedure? However any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) and create a search string from `emp.name`. Here is the [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4a0c/3)

```
select emp.id,
       emp.name emp_name, 
       dept.name dep_name from emp
join dept
where emp.dept_id=dept.id
      AND

      dept.name regexp 
        CONCAT('([[:<:]]',
               REPLACE(
                   TRIM(emp.name),
                   ' ',
                   '[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]'
               ),
               '[[:>:]])');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
*
FROM
emp
INNER JOIN dept ON emp.dept_id = dept.id
WHERE
emp.name LIKE CONCAT('%', dept.name, '%')
```

This will get you all employees whose name is in their department name. However if employee name column is prename **and** surname, this is bad database design and it's a bit harder to implement the "at least one common word" restriction. Either change DB schema by separating name into two columns or you will have to use the functions

- `substring()`
- `substring_index()`
- `length()`

to split the name and so on. This will get ugly. Read more about those functions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).

Anyway, have a try yourself or you won't learn it. This is not a "do all the work for me" site and there are more people willing to help when you at least show some research effort. Good luck.